# Retrieve documents based on the number of occurrences of a value in a certain field;

Tags: solr, solrj

So here is my problem. I have a solar index in which I add documents with several fields, one of them being "name". The question is: how could I retrieve the documents that have the value of the "name" field a value that occurs in more documents, given the fact that I know that the number of occurences must be in an interval [a,b], a,b are known values. For example i have

```
<doc>
  <field name="name">ana</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="name">gina</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="name">ana</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="name">ana</field>
</doc>
```

So i have 3 documents, and a=2 and b=3. So my query should return the 1st, 3rd and 4th document, because they contain the value "ana" for the field name, and the value ana occurs 3 times in the index, and 3 is in the interval [a,b] which is [2,3].

Thanks

Comment: facet.mincount and facet.limit, I guess? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.limit

Comment: This is a start yes, but the documents are not filtered by the facet params, i just receive an additional section in the results; how can I filter documents by these facet counts?